# Study material for fuzzy logic

Tags: probability, reference-request, fuzzy-logic

Can you please suggest some good study material on fuzzy logic. any good books, articles, video material would be appreciated. I am doing my Master's Diploma in Information Systems, and I need some background in fuzzy logic for it.

Comment: It would be good to know what level of education you are at. Do you know predicate logic? propositional logic? Godel theorem's?

Comment: yes I've got some knowledge in predicate logic and propositional logic. Don't know Godel's theorems though...

Answer (score 2):

If your interest on fuzzy logic is from a mathematical point of view (axiomatizations in propositional and predicate languages, etc.) I would strongly suggest Petr Hájek's book "Methamathematics of fuzzy logic" as a first step into this realm.

I suggest you take a look at the following links:
 http://www.mathfuzzlog.org/index.php/Mathematical_Fuzzy_Logic
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BL_%28logic%29
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_t-norm_logic

Comment: Thank you very much, I need more computer science oriented material, but this will be handy too, I'm sure.